# How to get position/index of xtick in matplotlib with label? (Python 3.6 | Matplotlib 2.0)

Tags: python, matplotlib, indexing, plot, label

I'm trying to get the region dedicated to the plot for a particular `xtick` label (not including marker size).  For example, `label='b'` seems to have the territory of `(0.5 - 1.5)` b/c the tick position is `1` and I believe the default tick width is `1`.

My question, **if I have a `query_label` (e.g. `query_label= "c"`) how can I get the `tick position` of `query_label` along the `x-axis` and the `tick width` without assuming each `tick` position is separated by a width of 1 (e.g. `[-1, 0, 1, 2, ...]`)?**

Basically, I would like to end up with:

`query_position = (1.5, 2.5) # for query_label = "c"`

Code for the simple example:

```
# Data
x = np.arange(5)
y = np.sqrt(x)
s = [1000]*5
c = ["aquamarine"]*5

# Plot
with plt.style.context("dark_background"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=s, edgecolors="ivory", linewidth=2.5)
    ax.set_xticklabels(list("-abcde"), fontsize=20)
    ax.grid(False, which="major")

# Trying to get the xtick info
ax.get_xticks()
# array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])

# How to get position and tick width? 
query_label= "c"
def get_position(query_label, ax):
    # stuff to get tick index
    # stuff to get tick width
    tick_padding = tick_width/2
    return (tick_index - tick_padding, tick_index + tick_padding)

# Results
query_position = get_position(query_label, ax)
query_position
# (1.5, 2.5)
```

Maybe there is a method in `matplotlib` analagous to `pd.Index(list("-abcde")).get_loc("c")`?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if there exists a method, but you can generate a dictionary using `ax.get_xticklabels()` which will return a list of `xticklabel` objects.

```
x_labels = list(ax.get_xticklabels())
```

These objects contain both the label and their positions, you can extract that into a dictionary using list comprehension.

```
x_label_dict = dict([(x.get_text(), x.get_position()[0]) for x in x_labels])
```

In case you want to exclude some of the tick labels you can use an if condition as:

```
x_label_dict = dict([(x.get_text(), x.get_position()[0]) for x in x_labels if x.get_text() not in ['', '-']])
```

Now the width of each tick labels can be determined using adjacent query labels as:

```
tick_width = x_label_dict['b'] - x_label_dict['a']
```

Hence the query position for `'c'` becomes

```
x_label_dict['c'] - tick_width/2, x_label_dict['c'] + tick_width/2
```

After determining the tick_width you can update the dictionary so that you can directly use it without the need for a function definition

```
x_query_position = {key: (x_label_dict[key]- tick_width/2, x_label_dict[key] + tick_width/2) for key in x_label_dict.keys()}
```

I guess the query position for `'c'` is `x_query_position['c']`

Comment: Note: this only works if you have already rendered the plot. Also, this code seems to assume you're only working with the x-coord of the labels, so I suspect you should use `x.get_position()[0]` in the second code block, as is done in the following one.